# Nsubstitute always returns null when argument is created inside method that is being tested

Tags: c#, unit-testing, .net-core, nunit, nsubstitute

Let's say we have a service with an injected unit of work

```
public class Service: IService
{ 
    IUnitOfWork unitOfWork;

   public Service(IUnitOfWork unitOfWork)
   {
       this.unitOfWork = unitOfWork;
   }

   public Item getResult(int id)
   {
       var parameter = new Parameter(id);        
      return _unitOfWork.Repository.GetItem(parameter);        

   }
}
```

And a service like this

```
public class Service: IService
{ 
    IUnitOfWork unitOfWork;

   public Service(IUnitOfWork unitOfWork)
   {
       this.unitOfWork = unitOfWork;
   }

   public Item getResult(Parameter parameter)
   {       
      return _unitOfWork.Repository.GetItem(parameter);        
   }
}
```

I want to test both services with a test using NUnit and NSubstitute that looks like this:

```
      public void Test()
      {
        Item item= new Item();
        item.Id = 22;

        Param param = new param(item.Id);
        IRepository repository = Substitute.For<IRepository>();
        repository.GetItem(param).Returns(item);

        IUnitOfWork unitOfWork = Substitute.For<UnitOfWork>(repository);

        IService sut= new Service(unitOfWork);


       // var result = service.GetResult(id) //Example for first service, returns null
        var result = service.GetResult(param)//Example for second service, returns item

        Assert.That(result.Id == item.Id);
      }
```

I want to know why the first service returns null when tested and second service returns proper result?

Comment: As a quick aside, I think the test should have `Substitute.For<IUnitOfWork>` (using the interface rather than the `UnitOfWork` class), or perhaps use the real `UnitOfWork` class. For NSubstitute we need to be [very careful using classes](https://nsubstitute.github.io/help/how-nsub-works/). Adding [NSubstitute.Analyzers](https://nsubstitute.github.io/help/nsubstitute-analysers/) to your test project will help pick up cases where this can cause a problem.

Comment: @David Tchepak Yeah i pretty much agree, the safest way to do it is to use interface, that being said this is just an example to highlight something different

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The second one works because the instance used in setting up the test is the exact one used when exercising the test, while the first one fails because the method under test uses its own instance.

You passed a reference to `param` here

```
repository.GetItem(param).Returns(item);
```

in the test setup while the subject service that fails uses its own object.

```
public Item getResult(int id) {
    var parameter = new Parameter(id);        
    return _unitOfWork.Repository.GetItem(parameter);
}
```

You are basically telling the mock "when `repository.GetItem` is given that specific object, return `item`" but in the subject it does not do that so the mock will not behave as expected.

If you want the test to work for both cases then the argument matching needs to be loosened.

You can either ignore the passed argument using `Arg.Any<T>`

```
public void Test() {
    var id = 22
    Item item = new Item();
    item.Id = id;

    var parameter = new Parameter(item.Id);

    IUnitOfWork unitOfWork = Substitute.For<IUnitOfWork>();
    //simplified to recursive mock
    unitOfWork.Repositoty.GetItem(Arg.Any<Parameter>()).Returns(item);

    IService service1 = new Service1(unitOfWork);
    IService service2 = new Service2(unitOfWork);

    //Act
    var result1 = service1.GetResult(id);
    var result2 = service2.GetResult(parameter);    

    //Assert
    Assert.That(result1.Id == item.Id);
    Assert.That(result2.Id == item.Id);
}
```

Or conditionally match the argument using `Arg.Is<T>(Predicate<T> condition)`.

Let's assume `Parameter` has a `object Value` property set via the constructor.

```
//...

var parameter = new Parameter(item.Id);

IUnitOfWork unitOfWork = Substitute.For<IUnitOfWork>();
//simplified to recursive mock
unitOfWork.Repositoty.GetItem(Arg.Is<Parameter>(p => p.Value == parameter.Value))
    .Returns(item);

//...
```

#### Reference [NSubstitute: Argument matchers](https://nsubstitute.github.io/help/argument-matchers/)